# ELB on Amazon - is it "worth it" in this case?

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-elb

We're thinking about moving to the Elastic Load Balancer on Amazon. However, it turns out that since we use more than one domain name, we would have to rename some of our applications to limit to a single ELB.  Another issue is we currently use free level one certificates, whereas moving to ELB would require moving up to level 2, although that's not a huge deal. Another issue is we don't have a lot of volume at this point, and don't really have a need for load-balancing in terms of traffic alleviation. Also, in the case of a failure of an amazon instance, which seems to be quite rare (have not experienced in several years), we can quickly be up and running by creating another instance and restoring.

Otoh, according to all I read about it, people are generally happy and recommend it, due to ease of setup and the value it brings.

Given the above, is it worth it?

Comment: Regarding multiple domains, use the new `Network Load Balancer` ... Not sure if this was release at the time of this OP though

Comment: That's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> since we use more than one domain name, we would have to rename some of our applications to limit to a single ELB

What makes you say this?  There's nothing preventing you from launching multiple ELB's if you really want to. And if your application already manages multiple domains properly then there's no reason a single ELB can't handle that either.  We currently have one ELB fronting an application on a bunch of EC2 instances that 11 different domains all point to.

> Another issue is we currently use free level one certificates, whereas moving to ELB would require moving up to level 2, although that's not a huge deal.

Not sure what you mean by "level one" and "level 2".  If you're using a self-signed SSL certificate then you'll need to switch to using certificate signed by a third party [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), which will indeed cost you some money.  Amazon supports all manner of certificates, including simple certs, EV certs, SAN certs, etc.  You'll find more information on ELB and SSL certs in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html).

> Also, in the case of a failure of an amazon instance, which seems to be quite rare (have not experienced in several years), we can quickly be up and running by creating another instance and restoring.

Consider yourself lucky.  We've had Amazon instances fail from time to time, and we also regularly get notifications from Amazon that instances need to be rebooted in order to migrate them off of faulty/old hardware.

If you really don't care about being down for a while and feel like you don't need the capacity that a load balancer and multiple appservers provides then there's no reason for you to move to using an ELB.  However if you want the reliability of multiple appservers then moving to an ELB is indeed a good idea.

And if you anticipate your traffic level growing then you might want to consider using Amazon's [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) tools. Using Auto Scaling you basically tell Amazon the minimum number of application servers you want running behind an ELB, and some parameters to indicate when they should automatically launch additional instances if/when load increases.

Our Amazon account rep actually recommended to us that if we had even a single instance that we wanted to minimize downtime of (like a monitoring server, etc) that we should create an Auto Scaling group with a limit of exactly 1 instance in it.  That way if the instance ever does die for any reason whatsoever, Amazon will automatically spin up a new replacement instance.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bruce, just wanted to add my 5 cents about Auto Scaling(ASG) and " Amazon will automatically spin up a new replacement instance.".

This is really cool way to get robust hosting solution, but will need some challenge to create CloudFormation template and bash auto install script that will be called from CloudFormation template to install all server software and deploy your app code.

So if you will have 2 instances and ASG with Min/Max = 2, then if some instance will be crashed, ASG will recreate it automaticly with all software installed and code deployed and ready to go

Also if you need to handle some periodic traffic jumps automaticly, then you can change the ASG as (Min=2, Max=5), create 2 CloudWatch alarms:
1. if cpu usage is 90+ for 5 or 10 mins
2. if cpu usage is 30- for 5 or 10 mins

Then assign Alarm 1 to scale up 1 additional instance and assign alarm 2 to destroy any additional instance created by 1